# Проблемма следующего характера Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: webpack, loader

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[0] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use.loader should be a non-empty string.
      -> A loader request.


const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const devMode = mode === 'development';
const target = devMode ? 'web' : 'browserslist';
const devtool = devMode ? 'source-map' : undefined;

module.exports = {
  mode,
  target,
  devtool,
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: './static'
  },
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill", path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js")],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    clean: true,
    filename: "[name].js",
    assetModuleFilename: (pathData) => {
      const filepath = path
        .dirname(pathData.filename)
        .split("/")
        .slice(1)
        .join("/");
      return `${filepath}/[name][ext]`;
    },
  },
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/html/uhing.html",
      filename: "uhing.html",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        use: {
          loader: ['html-loader', 'template-ejs-loader'],
          generator: {
            filename: "[name].html",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(c|sa|sc)ss$/i,
        use: [
          devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [require("postcss-preset-env")],
              },
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "fonts/[name][ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|webp|gif|svg)?$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: () => {
            return devMode
              ? "img/[name][ext]"
              : "img/[name].[contenthash][ext]";
          },
        },
     
        use: [
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
              },
           
              optipng: {
                enabled: false,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: [0.65, 0.9],
                speed: 4,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
            
              webp: {
                quality: 75,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    test: /\.html$/i,
    use: ["html-loader", "template-ejs-loader"],
    generator: {
        filename: "[name].html",
      },
  },
```

Решение заключалось в правильном использовании use